# How to link a button and text to the same link with php

Tags: php, html, image, button, hyperlink

```
<p style="" class="remove-item">
   <a href="<?php
   echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/delete', array('id' => $item->getId(), Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl())); ?>" style="font-size: 8.5px; float: right; margin-right: 6px; color: #cc0909; font-weight: bold"><?php echo $this->__(''); ?> 
Remove item
   <a class="remove-item-red" style="float: right; margin-right: 2px; margin-top: 2px"></a>
   </a>                                         
</p>
```

I was wondering how to get an img and the text that states Remove button to link to the same place. The img is the `<a class="remove-item-red">`, a red circle with an x in the middle. So both the img and the text need to serve the same function but whenever I meddle with the a class for my btn, it tends to crash or the usual that the button itself does not serve the function while the text does.

I had Remove item as `<?php echo $this->__('Remove item'); ?>` before which still resulted in the same, with Remove item doing its function while the a class button does nothing. It's just an image.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Simply moving the the a tag below the remove-item-red still does not link it, that's the first thing I tried to do when it didn't work.

Comment: <img src="../images/remove_red.png" style="height: 11px; width: 11px; display: block; background-position: 0 0px; float: right; margin-right: 2px; margin-top: 2px" />

I've changed the remove-item-red class into a img src and pulling it up.  It recognizes the image as a link now but doesn't show the actual img.  I commented out the div in the stylesheet as well.

Comment: As you said only the text href is working not the image, and i presume you need both the image and text to remove some div element. What you can do is you can take input type iamge and on its onClick event use style.display="none".

Comment: UPDATE:  The issue has been resolved and another getURL was necessary to be added in the a class remove-item-red for it work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a div-tag for the Remove button instead of embedding an a-tag in another a-tag.

Like so:

```
<p style="" class="remove-item">
  <a href="#">
    Remove item
    <div class="remove-item-red"></div>
  </a>                                            
</p>
```

Comment: I tried that as well and the div class itself still is not capable of being linked to the href for whatever reason.